# How can I pass an already instantiated IOC container to an Asp.net 5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Using .Net core I have created a console application that self hosts an asp.net 5 for endpoint support (to receive notifications, health checks, etc...).

While reading about [dependency injection in Asp.net 5](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) it shows how to use a custom IoC container, but it instantiates the container from within the Asp.net 5 `ConfigureServices()` method.

The problem this poses in a console application that also hosts an asp.net 5 application is that it appears that the `WebHostBuilder` instantiates a new instance of the `Startup` class, and while you can change which class is the "startup" class with `.UseStartup<MySTartup>()` you still can't control which instance of `MyStartup` Asp.net uses, which means there's no way to pass it an already setup container.

Is there a way (without using globals) to set up an IoC container and pass it to Asp.Net 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing Github, it appears like this is not possible.  Asp.net 5 must always be the creator of the ioc container, and the only way to share an IOC container with the rest of the application is to grab it from `IWebApplication.ApplicationServices` property to be used in the rest of the app.

I raised a [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/550) to hopefully get this resolved at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, but you can. If I understand your problem correctly, this should provide the behavior you need:

> When an ASP.NET 5 application starts, the Startup class is used to
>   bootstrap the application, load its configuration settings, etc.
>   (learn more about ASP.NET startup). However, if a class exists named
>   Startup{EnvironmentName} (for example StartupDevelopment), and the
>   ASPNET_ENV environment variable matches that name, then that Startup
>   class is used instead.

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html#startup-conventions

As for passing the container around, it's best to avoid that. As a last resort you can rely on the technique I used prior to working with DI-friendly frameworks: when bootstrapping the container instance at startup, use reflection to find IoC configurations in loaded assemblies, and call their methods, passing in the container.

Comment: That says I can tell it which class to use as the Startup class but not which *Instance*.  I need to get ahold of the instance of the class so that I can pass the IOC container to it.  I'm also not sure why it's a bad idea for Asp.Net infrastructure and the console portions of my application to use the same IOC container. Also I almost always use reflection to setup IOC but the problem with the current setup is I have to have two mechanisms to codify those IoC conventions, and keep them in sync

Comment: @KallDrexx Gotcha. Ok, so if you add an `IServiceProvider` parameter to the constructor of the class containing your console app's main entry point, the framework should then inject the provider that you're returning from `ConfigureServices`. You can then pass that in to the constructor of the `WebHostBuilder` you're using to start the ASP.NET app.

Comment: Nope, that seems to be removed from RC1.  As of RC1 you must always have a static entry point again :( https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/113